# How to connect .net 2.0 framework application to SQL Server 2014 using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2014, .net-2.0

I have an application runing on .net 2.0 framework with SQL Server 2008. Our DBA is asking to migrate the app to SQL Server 2014 database.

My problem is that I cannot open database connection executing the following instructions:

```
Dim conDB As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
conDB = New SqlConnection(ConnectString)
conDB.Open()
```

Do you know which SQL Server version .net framework 2.0 supports (the file System.Data.dll)?

How can I open it? Should I install something or should I change .Net framework?

For information: I have the SQL Server 2016 Management Studio installed on my machine and I have no issues with it. I can connect to my SQL Server 2014 database.

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what actually happens when you execute that code.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: If you have the **correct** connection string, you should have no trouble at all to connect from .NET 2.0 to a SQL Server 2014 database. My 2 cents are on an *invalid* connection string. .....

Comment: YES! You was right, there was a mistake in the string. It was so evident. Sorry for disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the mistake was so evident: in the connection string.